# GetNumberOfEventLogRecords returns incorrect number of event logs

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, service, event-log

I have this C++ code to read the event log records

```
DWORD GetLogRecords(LPCWSTR wsLogFile)
{
  HANDLE hEvt = OpenEventLog(NULL, wsLogFile);
  if (hEvt==NULL) return 0;

  DWORD dwTotalRecords;
  BOOL res = GetNumberOfEventLogRecords(hEvt, &dwTotalRecords);
  CloseEventLog(hEvt);

  return (res != 0) ? dwTotalRecords : 0;
}
```

Result

```
atlTraceGeneral - C:\Windows\system32\winevt\logs\ACEEventLog.evtx - 23499 Total Records
atlTraceGeneral - C:\Windows\system32\winevt\logs\Application.evtx - 23499 Total Records
atlTraceGeneral - C:\Windows\system32\winevt\logs\ConnectionInfo.evtx - 23499 Total Records
atlTraceGeneral - C:\Windows\system32\winevt\logs\Error.evtx - 23499 Total Records
atlTraceGeneral - C:\Windows\system32\winevt\logs\HardwareEvents.evtx - 23499 Total Records
atlTraceGeneral - C:\Windows\system32\winevt\logs\Internet Explorer.evtx - 23499 Total Records
atlTraceGeneral - C:\Windows\system32\winevt\logs\Key Management Service.evtx - 23499 Total Records
 ...
```

I have called this function with the full path of all the .EVTX log files on my computer (150 log files). And each time it returns 23499 ! My log files have different sizes and some 0, why I always get 23499 ?

UPDATE2: After I have cleared the Application logs now I get 0 for all the .evtx log files. I think it always gets the application log instead of the specified .evtx file.

UPDATE: As Remy Lebeau suggested, but still the same result.

Comment: *If you specify a custom log and it cannot be found, the event logging service opens the Application log* so there's your answer, and the problem must be in code you haven't shown us.

Comment: The code is here and the .evtx files path are correct.

Comment: Have you tried to run the above function and specify an .evtx log file and it worked?

Comment: Based on the sample [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb427356(v=vs.85).aspx) I would guess the problem is you're specifying the full path and you're not meant to. Note they call `OpenEventLog` with the string `"MyEventProvider"` - no path, not even a file extension.

Comment: But I want to get the total number of records of each event log file, not of providers.

Comment: Just give it a try... (e.g. `"HardwareEvents"` instead of `"c:\\windows\\....\\HardwareEvents.evtx"`)

Comment: That is because the channel have the same name as the log file, but what about this "Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy%4Operational" instead of "c:\\windows\\...\\Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy%4Operational.evtx"

Comment: Dunno, again just try it.

Comment: Thanks! You're right

Comment: I suspect your other question is basically the same problem.

Comment: Probably it have the same problem, you cannot open the .evtx using full path. But I have opened the logs as you suggested and then with the old ClearEventLog function I was able to clear all of them. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the benefit of others, the solution to this problem is that `OpenEventLog` doesn't accept a pathname. Instead you have to give it the *source name* of the event log (something like `"HardwareEvents"`).

If you call `OpenEventLog` with an invalid source name (which includes providing a pathname), then as documented it will open the `Application` log instead:

> If you specify a custom log and it cannot be found, the event logging
>   service opens the Application log.

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking the result of `GetNumberOfEventLogRecords()` for an error. And you are leaking the log handle.  Try this instead:

```
DWORD GetLogRecords(LPCWSTR wsLogFile)
{
  HANDLE hEvt = OpenEventLog(NULL, wsLogFile);
  if (hEvt==NULL) return 0;

  DWORD dwTotalRecords;
  BOOL res = GetNumberOfEventLogRecords(hEvt, &dwTotalRecords);
  CloseEventLog(hEvt);

  return (res != 0) ? dwTotalRecords : 0;
}
```

Comment: did not help, I still get 23498 records now on all the .EVTX log files.

Comment: Did you debug the code to verify that `GetLogRecord()` is actually returning 23498, and that you are not simply corrupting the value when you are outputting it in your trace messages?

Comment: Yes I did. I think it everytime it reads the Application log, because I have cleared the Application log and now I get 0 for all the logs.