# Get Incorrect handle as error with GetFileSizeEx

Tags: c++, winapi, event-log, event-viewer

My goal is to find the size of log files which is present in (%SystemRoot%\System32\winevt\logs) using c++ (For Eg : To get the file size of Application.evtx). I tried with GetFileSizeEx (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfilesizeex) method but i got error like incorrect handle is passed. Passed three handle with (EvtQuery,EvtGetChannelConfigProperty,OpenEventLog) to GetFileSizeEx but i get the same error. Can i know what handle should be passed to get the size:

Find the similar question ([How to find the size of log files using EvtQuery function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51857513/how-to-find-the-size-of-log-files-using-evtquery-function)). Tried this but I got invalid handle as error with GetFileSizeEx.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size

Comment: @Naresh please post *YOUR* code that uses GetFileSizeEx

Answer (score 0):

The default file location is `C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs`

The application log is called `Application.evtx`

If you want to get its size do

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

int main() {

    std::filesystem::path example = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\winevt\\Logs\\Application.evtx";
    std::cout << example << " size = " << std::filesystem::file_size(example) << '\n';
}
```

If you want to be sure to get the correct location becuase an admin can move it then look here in the registry

```
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application\File
```

to get the file name

Comment: I get exception like "The system cannot find the path specified." . I think there is only one way to get the log file size by using winapi's . Because i get the same error ("The system cannot find the path specified") when i tried using file operation and stats.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Doc:[GetFileSizeEx function](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfilesizeex)

> The handle must have been created with the FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES access
> right or equivalent, or the caller must have sufficient permission on
> the directory that contains the file.

Whether you have checked the result of opening the file to get the file handle? If the file failed to open, you're calling `GetFileSizeEx` with an invalid handle.

Comment: Handle is created without any error . I can do other operation with the handle